# Why does Ubuntu handle keyboard shortcuts on-release while other distributions don't?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I like trying different Linux distributions from time to time.

I love keyboard shortcuts and one thing that drives me crazy about a distribution is the fact that it handles keyboard shortcuts **on-pressing**, rather than **on-releasing**.

This allows a keyboard shortcut such as <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> to trigger its action when I actually want to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, because the system doesn't give me the chance to press the <kbd>R</kbd> once the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys are pressed

Ubuntu and Linux Mint handle this well. It doesn't trigger the shortcut unless I release the pressed keys.

So why does Ubuntu handle this well? What aspect of the Linux system is responsible for that? I need to filter out other Linux distributions that I can try, based on this criterion, which is to be able to handle keyboard shortcuts properly.

A side question: I consider this a MAJOR ISSUE. How on earth does it still exist at all?!

Comment: Is this behavior by default on Ubuntu? It seems to me that the shortcuts are actually recognized on-press. I tried `Ctrl + Alt + T`, and it opened the Terminal (several times) without me releasing.

Comment: @fakedad What version are you using? I tried this on Linux Mint (Rosa, Ubuntu 14.04) and Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Comment: I tested this on Ubuntu 16.04.1 (using Unity), and Lubuntu 16.04.1 (using LXDE).

Comment: I'm getting similar results (recognizing on-press) with Linux Mint "Rosa" with Cinnamon. Granted, I'm using a virtual machine for this and my testing of Ubuntu 16.04.1, but my testing with Lubuntu was with a physical machine.

Comment: @fakedad With Mint, I was using Mate. I'll try downloading and testing this for Lubuntu. And I don't "think" testing this using a virtual machine through a host is valid because the rules of the host would still apply. But don't you think this is a terrible way to handle keyboard shortcuts ? What if you wanted to press a third key ?

Comment: I just tested out Linux Mint "Rosa" with MATE on a physical machine, and I'm still having no luck reproducing the recognition on-release. I have noticed that, with Mint on both MATE and Cinnamon, however, the shortcut activated by pressing the Windows/super key does seem to activate on-release. Still, other shortcuts seem to release on-press for me.

Comment: Would you please try adding another keyboard layout and try switching using `Alt + Shift` keys ? Does they work on-releasing or on-pressing ?

Comment: I just tried that on Linux Mint "Rosa" with MATE and I wasn't able to get Alt Shift to switch the keyboard layout at all (maybe I had the settings wrong?), but I was able to get it to work with Lubuntu 16.04.1. The keyboard layout switched on-release, as you had suggested. At this point, I'm really not sure what determines whether a keyboard shortcut is recognized on-press or on-release.

Comment: @fakedad The `Alt + Shift` keys combination usually needs to be configured to switch keyboard layouts as they usually aren't the default. My question is about keyboard shortcuts generally, not about `Alt + Shift` specifically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OS keyboard shortcuts conflict with apps keyboard shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009352/os-keyboard-shortcuts-conflict-with-apps-keyboard-shortcuts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [Xorg bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865). Fixed [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xorg-server-bug865/) for Manjaro Linux. I had to follow [these steps](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository#Installing_from_the_AUR_by_hand) to manually skip PGP checking !