# OS keyboard shortcuts conflict with apps keyboard shortcuts in GNOME 3

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell, shortcut-keys

I have Ubuntu 16.04 with GNOME shell. I set <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> for the "Modifiers-only switch to next source" option.

This shortcut conflicts with apps hot-keys. I can't use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to open devtools in Chrome, it just switches the layout. In VS code IDE if I press shortcuts with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> (for example <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>), shortcuts work but always switch a keyboard layout. When I used Windows this problem didn't exist.

Can I set the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> shortcut in such a way that it causes a switch action only after the keys are released and only if this 2 keys were pressed (without additional keys)?

Comment:  2021 it is still there

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Try [@N0rbert's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1009356/480481) first.

---

It's actually a bug (see [this](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=712667%20) and [this](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865)). Unfortunately it seems it's not going to be fixed (first one marked as "*RESOLVED WONTFIX*").

As a workaround you may have to remove those shortcuts and get used to the default ones to switch layouts (<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> & <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>).

Answer (score 22):

It is known [bug 1245473](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1245473).

Nobody cares about it even on modern [Ubuntu Community](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/keyboard-layout-switching-problems-and-poll/2876).

I'm citing my [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/968105/66509) here:

> Myself I found only one resolution - I'll stay on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS MATE until 2021 year ([really 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) because it's Ubuntu flavor).

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS MATE I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> without issues.

---

I have created [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Enrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/xorg-hotkeys) with patched packages for:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (*xenial*) with xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (*bionic*)
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (*bionic*) with xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
- Ubuntu 18.10 (*cosmic*)
- Ubuntu 19.04 (*disco*)
- Ubuntu 19.10 (*eoan*)
- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (*focal*)
- Ubuntu 20.10 (*groovy*)
- Ubuntu 21.04 (*hirsute*)
- Ubuntu 21.10 (impish)

You can test them by the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nrbrtx/xorg-hotkeys
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**Warranty disclaimer:** packages were tested in

- 16.04 LTS with HWE (Unity, MATE, Xfce)
- 18.04 LTS (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Xfce)
- 18.10 (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Xfce)
- 19.04 (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Unity, Xfce)
- 19.10 (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Unity, Xfce)
- 20.04 LTS (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Unity, Xfce)
- 20.10 (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Unity, Xfce)
- 21.04 (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Xfce)
- 21.10 (Cinnamon, KDE, MATE, Xfce)

However other desktops may have issues even after applying the patch.
These packages do not fix problems for GNOME Shell (18.04 LTS, 18.10, 19.04, 19.10, 20.04 LTS, 20.10 and 21.04) and Unity (in 18.04 LTS and 18.10). To remove GNOME Shell and install other desktop follow my other answers - for [18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/a/1266925/66509) and for [20.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233026/66509).

Comment: Ubuntu flavors like Ubuntu MATE have LTS releases lasting only three years rather than five, so [MATE 16.04 is only good until April 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases).

Comment: Thanks, but I hope that my system will not compromised between 2019 and 2021 :)

Comment: Worked on KDE (kubuntu 20.04) for me and fixed all the konsole conflicts as well.

Comment: Working but layout switching takes about 0.5 seconds. It is very not handy. Thanks to the author of this patch he says how to remove it.