# Ctrl+Shift+T doesn't restore closed tab

Tags: 18.04, chromium, wayland

In Ubuntu 18.04 with Ubuntu-Wayland.
I configured <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> for switching keyboard layout.

And now in chrome <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> doesn't restore closed tab but only opens empty tab as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
How to fix it.

P.S. In Mint with KDE same configuration but all work perfectly.

Comment: See [my answer in duplicate thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/1009356/66509).