# In 18.04 moving window to other workplace doesn't work with alternate language switch enabled

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 18.04, language-support

I've upgraded a 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS where language switching already had the alternative combination of <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>.

While changing languages works, it appears that moving a window to a different workplace with key combinations like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd>, fails and acts as the same keypress but without <kbd>alt</kbd>, which just changes the workplace.

I've confirmed with `xev` that each individual keypress and combination get detected, with the exception that when <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> are active at the same time, regardless of holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or letting the keys go, the `keysum` named  `ISO_Next_Group` appears and any further detection is blocked.

If I remove the alternate language switch combination (using `gnome-tweeks`) everything works fine.

I've tried to replace the default language switch of <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> from `settings`->`keyboard` and it's not detecting *any* keypress of <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> unless another key is pressed. This means I can not set <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> but maybe <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> which I don't want.

It looks like there's a similar [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1245473/+index?comments=all) with about 300 comments from... 2004 till today (2018), but I'm not sure if it applies to the exact problem because it was working till now and I can't believe the exact same problem can be 15y old and noone ever bothered.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OS keyboard shortcuts conflict with apps keyboard shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009352/os-keyboard-shortcuts-conflict-with-apps-keyboard-shortcuts) . I hope that my PPA may fix your issue. And it is unbelievable that Xorg, Debian and Ubuntu developers do not care about this bug for [14 years](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865)(!!!!).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it is quite possible this fix will do, as it moves detection of combinations to when keys are released instead of pressed. I will come back with the results. Does anyone know why it _used_ to work in 16.04 and stopped in 18.04? Is it the switch to gnome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested linked question [OS keyboard shortcuts conflict with apps keyboard shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009352/os-keyboard-shortcuts-conflict-with-apps-keyboard-shortcuts) did the trick for me.

It still remains a mystery why it worked in Ubuntu till 18.04.