# Keyboard language layout switching interferes with global system hotkeys

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, kde, keyboard-layout

I have installed Kubuntu 18.04 with KDE on my home machine.

I usually use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> for switching keyboard language layout, but that setting breaks <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> selecting by word behavior (or any other hotkey containing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>) — instead of selecting text by word it switches keyboard layout.
I have switched to using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> for language layout switching, but that interferes with JetBrains' IDE hotkey <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (or any other hotkey containing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>) — instead of intended action in IDE it simply switches keyboard layout.

On another machine with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS I successfully use both layout switching hotkeys without any issues, so there must be something I'm missing in keyboard configuration.
The question is: why regular keyboard layout switching hotkey interferes with global system hotkeys effectively overriding and breaking them? How to fix that behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OS keyboard shortcuts conflict with apps keyboard shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009352/os-keyboard-shortcuts-conflict-with-apps-keyboard-shortcuts). Also see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language/1029605?s=1|0.0000#1029605). I hope  my PPA will help.

Comment: It really is and your answer should probably be the accepted one. Installing your PPA package helped.