# Can't bind Ctrl+Shift+key if Ctrl+key is bound

Tags: gnome, 18.04, shortcut-keys

Somehow when I bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> with any typeable key in the Gnome's keyboard settings, then the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> can't be used anywhere. The programs in which I use this key combo don't respond at all. When I don't bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> in Gnome, then the programs respond to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> normally.

I stumbled upon this because I want to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> which many programs use as *quit*. I read in different places that I can 'disable' a shortcut by re-binding it to `/bin/false` or `/bin/true`. While this worked like a charm in Unity, it doesn't seem to work the same way in Gnome, and Gnome is now the new window manager of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

1. Can someone give me a deeper explanation about what's going on here?
2. How can I disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> without disabling <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (without going back to Unity)?

Comment: Does this ( https://askubuntu.com/q/1009352/66509 ) look similar?

Comment: No that's about using just the modifier keys without a typeable key