# Ubuntu 18.04.1 not recognizing Ctrl + Alt

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

My <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> key combination is not recognized by my OS. My <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys both work individually. I am simply not able to use any shortcuts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> together.

I am fairly certain that something is intercepting the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> command as soon as I click <kbd>Alt</kbd>. However, in my keyboard settings, there is nothing that uses the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> hotkey. I even did a reset of all the keyboard shortcuts to be sure.

The reason why I think something is intercepting it, is that I installed some software involving switching to a Latin keyboard using the (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> hotkey). And I do not know how to change this setting.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: For example, I would like to use the standard <Ctrl> + <Alt> + <T> shortcut to open up a terminal. The fact of the matter is is that I cannot use any <Ctrl> + <Alt> [+ X] hotkey where X is any combination of keys.

Comment: Yes, I think that may be the case but I am unsure on how to change it. When I go to Settings --> Region & Language --> Input Sources Options, I see that the keyboard shortcut for ¨Alternative switch to next source" is set to <Alt> + <Ctrl>. It says that I can change this shortcut in the keyboard settings but I see no such option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known issue with GNOME shell, shortcuts get triggered on-keypress instead of on-release (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009352/os-keyboard-shortcuts-conflict-with-apps-keyboard-shortcuts)). Since you have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> set to change the keyboard layout, whenever you attempt to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>something</kbd>, the shell registers only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> immediately after you've pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd> and changes the layout.

You can disable this <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> combination using **(GNOME) Tweaks**. First install it by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

and use the tool to disable the combination. Refer to this for details: [Ubuntu 17.10 and later: can't change the input switching shortcut to alt+shift](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967364/ubuntu-17-10-and-later-cant-change-the-input-switching-shortcut-to-altshift)

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: In my case, with Ubuntu 22.04 following this was not enough. I had to set the Ctrl+Alt (+ArrowUp/Down in my case) combination as Gnome shortcut for something meaningless and disable the shortcuts afterwards. This overwrites the hidden Gnome shortcut. [reference1](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179748#issuecomment-1506432965) and [reference2](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206868075/comments/10196831748242)

Answer (score 1):

I came looking for a solution to why some software I had installed (VS Code) couldn't register the input of my desired keys (<kbd>⬆</kbd> or <kbd>⬇</kbd>) as an addendum to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> sequence. The essential problem is the same, but the specifics of my fresh Ubuntu install (22.04 LTS) are different from what the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080874/618353) identifies as the solution.

Ubuntu's built-in settings *Keyboard Shortcuts* didn't list the shortcuts described, and neither did `gnome-tweaks`. Further searching around the topic of GNOME keyboard shortcuts led me to the question [Ubuntu 17.10 and later: can't change the input switching shortcut to alt+shift](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967364/ubuntu-17-10-and-later-cant-change-the-input-switching-shortcut-to-altshift), and the answers there put me on the right path:

The built-in command line interface for GNOMEs desktop key bindings is [`gsettings`](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/GSettings), stored under the schema `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`. You can list all of these as key-value pairs by running

```sh
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
```

Scrolling through the list, I was able to find the following entries

```sh
# ...
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down ['<Control><Alt>Down']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-last ['<Super>End']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left ['<Super>Page_Up', '<Super><Alt>Left', '<Control><Alt>Left']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right ['<Super>Page_Down', '<Super><Alt>Right', '<Control><Alt>Right']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up ['<Control><Alt>Up']
# ...
```

To get rid of these bindings, I ran the following commands:

```sh
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down '[]'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up '[]'
```

The change requires restarting the session by logging out & back in order to take effect.

If any mistake is made, the settings can be reverted with

```sh
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up
```