# problem with shortcuts ubuntu 18.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, 18.10

While upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10, a prompt came out asking something about Latin and non-Latin keyboards (I have also installed the greek keyboard) and switching between them. I was given a drop-down menu for shortcuts and I chose left ctrl+ left shift. When I try the shortcut nothing happens.

When the installation finished, I noticed that when I use the left shift for the Mozilla shortcut ctrl+shift+tab for switching to the previous tab, it goes forward. When I use the right shift key the shortcut functions.

Same thing with the ctrl+shift+T shortcut for restoring the last closed tab.

I think that the two things are related.

Is there anyway I can undo this thing? I'm left-handed and it's quite annoying, besides being a stupid bug...

Thanks.

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080851/ubuntu-18-04-1-not-recognizing-ctrl-alt

Answer (score 1):

Open the `Activities`, type `Settings` --> go to `Devices` --> `Keyboard`

Then click the row that you want and you'll see the window `Set shortcut`

Hold down the desired key combination (press backspace to reset or esc to cancel).

Comment: the problem is that i'm stuck with "alternative switch to next source" which is left ctrl + left shift and i cannot change that from the settings. i can only change "switch to next source". i can see the "alternative switch" in settings -> languages -> options, but not in the keyboard->shortcuts part.