# How can Shift+Alt+Tab navigation be enabled in GNOME when Alt+Shift cycles between multiple keyboard layouts?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, window-manager, application-switcher

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and have used GNOME Tweaks(1) to restore normal keyboard layout switching behavior where pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> cycles between enabled layouts. I've also used Gnome Settings(2) in an attempt to restore normal windows switching where <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> brings up a list of windows and moves the selected window from the most recently-used window to the least, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> moves the cursor in the opposite direction.

Keyboard layout works well. Window switching does not: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behaves as expected but <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does not because it changes the keyboard layout rather than traverse the window list.

How can I restore normal <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> functionality when using multiple layouts? I *know* it's possible because I've read a blog post on how to do it once, however I was unable to find said blog post again.

---

Edit: Found it! See: https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2015/10/02/gnome-altshift-and-altshifttab/

Edit2: I believe this is not a duplicate of [OS keyboard shortcuts conflict with apps keyboard shortcuts in GNOME 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009352/os-keyboard-shortcuts-conflict-with-apps-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gnome-3) because it's specific to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and that specificity seems to have allowed for an acceptable workaround. See my answer below.

---

Notes:

1. The setting is under Tweaks > Keyboard & Mouse > Additional Layout Options.
2. Normal Keyboard Shortcut reassignment.

Comment: Alt+Shift is already assigned as a short cut. So when 3 keys are combined, it is catching up the short cut Alt+Shift or Shift+Alt..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OS keyboard shortcuts conflict with apps keyboard shortcuts in GNOME 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009352/os-keyboard-shortcuts-conflict-with-apps-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gnome-3)

Comment: @PRATAP I agee, that's exactly what's happening. However, when the windows list appears (after you press `Alt`+`Tab`), pressing `Shift` with `Tab` again to reverse the direction of traversal without effecting layout should still be possible with GNOME 3. The issue is that I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: The *underlying issue* raised in this question is actually the same as the one raised in [OS keyboard shortcuts conflict with apps keyboard shortcuts in GNOME 3](https://askubuntu.com/q/1009352/480481) (that GNOME shortcuts are triggered *on key-press* rather than *on-release*, so keyboard layout is switched *as soon as* you 're done pressing <Shift>+<Alt> while you're in fact trying to press <Shift>+<Alt>+<Tab>). However the other question is kinda broader. Thanks a lot for digging deep to find a workaround for the *specific* issue in your question and sharing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a workaround that allows you to keep using both shortcuts normally:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> both work.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> cycles between layouts normally.

The only caveat is that reversing window traversal with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will also change the layout once. This is an acceptable compromise in my case.

The way this is done is to:

1. Open gnome tweaks tool
2. Go to Keyboard & Mouse
3. Click on "Additional Layout Options"
4. Expand "Miscellaneous Compatibility Options"
5. Check "Shift cancels Caps Lock"

I want to mimic PRATAP's helpful answer by posting the steps in pictures:

1. step-1:
   [image: step-1]
2. step-2:
   [image: step-2]
3. step-3:
   [image: step-3]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu :) If this solves your problem please consider ["accepting" the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking the tick (✓) next to it) to indicate you've found a working solution and also so that others may more easily find it in the future. Since the answer is also posted by you, you'll be able to accept it after 2 days, not right now (you can accept an answer posted by someone else after a few minutes).

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome. I plan to accept whichever answer gets the most votes after a few days since I'm not sure this solution will be acceptable for everyone. Also, thank you for fixing up my posts.

Answer (score 1):

as a workaround,
Left Alt+Left Shift for "Switching to another Layout"

now, pressing Left Alt+ Right Shift+ TAB  solved it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help. I really appreciated it. However, I managed to find the webpage that I mentioned in my op, and it presents a workaround that that allows using the same `Shift` and `Alt` keys for both window navigation and layout cycling. See my answer  https://askubuntu.com/a/1115722/921352