# Keyboard layout shortcut interferes with Firefox shortcut

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, firefox, input-language, gnome-tweaks

I am multi-lingual, and I use several keyboard language layouts.
I am used to using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> in Windows to changue input language, so I want the same for my Linux. Default <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> is very inconvenient for me.  Ubuntu's vanilla settings app doesn't allow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> combination, so I had to use the Gnome Tweaks application, which allows more flexible options--including <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> for shortcuts.

However, I noticed that now Firefox's shortcut to undo closing a tab (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), which I use extremely frequently, stopped working. It seems that as soon as Gnome/Ubuntu registers a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> key combo, it stops caring if any other keys are pressed as well. It just switches keyboard layout with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> the same way it does with just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

This is a major quality of life issue for me. How do I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you, very informative.

I just installed KDE on the same Ubuntu/Gnome installation using tasksel as described here:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-kde-plasma-desktop-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

And it's having the same problem. I wonder if it's because KDE is installed in parallel to Gnome.

I have wasted so much time to make basic things work (even mic doesn't work on my "Ubuntu certified" laptop. Lots of bugs. I don't see Linux ever hitting any double digits in market share with this amount of ancient bugs and low quality of life.

Comment: As you may know from [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1009356/66509) - you have to remove (or switch from) GNOME, add my PPA and install other DE like MATE or Xfce.