# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS - Ctrl + Shift not working

Tags: shortcut-keys

My buttons **Ctl + Shift + X** - not working.

It is working just as **Ctrl + X**

For example:
Ctrl + Shift + F - find in files (Sublime Text) - works as Ctrl + F

Ctrl + Shift + H - replace files (Sublime Text) - works as Ctl + H

Ctrl + Shift + T - open recently closed tab (Chrome) - work as Ctr+ T - new tab

Comment: How many keyboard layouts do you have? Do you switch them by `<Ctrl>+<Shift>`?

Comment: I have 2 language layouts. Yes, I have <Ctrl>+<Shift> switch

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/1009352/66509 .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OS keyboard shortcuts conflict with apps keyboard shortcuts in GNOME 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009352/os-keyboard-shortcuts-conflict-with-apps-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gnome-3)