# Alt+Shift to switch language conflicts with Alt+Shift+Tab for previous window

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04.
I use `gnome-tweaks` to map `Alt+Shift` to swtich language.
The problem is that when I use `Alt+Tab` to switch window, the option to press `Alt+Shift+Tab` (which supposed to be "previous window") doesn't work, and instead the language input is changing.

How can I resolve this conflict? I want both shortcuts to work.

Comment: You may want to choose another key combination for switching languages as it conflicts with the Alt+Tab functionality, like you see. There are quite some options. Else change the Alt+Shift+Tab. You will need to choose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OS keyboard shortcuts conflict with apps keyboard shortcuts in GNOME 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009352/os-keyboard-shortcuts-conflict-with-apps-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gnome-3) . [Remove GNOMEs Hell](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233026/66509), install Xfce, KDE or MATE with [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Enrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/xorg-hotkeys) instead.

Comment: @N0rbert First, Kudos to you for the PPA and patches. I'm not sure I want to purge Gnome? I use many gnome-shell extensions.